# Angular2 ngZone updating models/variables only on Event

Tags: angular

my ng2-app only update its view after an angular2 view event occured. This problem occured since i updated my ng2-app from rc.4 to final. After some event (e.g. blur) the view get updated, if i change the model with some code my view won't get updated until next event. Everytime i trigger an event (blur event) i got this error message:

```
Error: Expected to not be in Angular Zone, but it is!
    at Function.NgZone.assertNotInAngularZone (core.umd.js:6081)
    at Object.next (core.umd.js:6288)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.umd.js:5952)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:190)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:135)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.ts:61)
    at EventEmitter.emit (core.umd.js:5944)
    at eval (core.umd.js:6180)
```

Do you know this error after upgrading your application to @NgModule-syntax? Maybe it has something to do with lazy loaded components. Hope you can help me to get rid of this error... Maybe it has something to do with rc.4 precompile array on @component? i really need help

Comment: Can you edit your question with your import list on your app.module.ts? I've had a similar problem before where I imported "BrowserDynamicTestingModule"